# Is there any swagger.json tag for JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT?

Tags: java, json, jackson, swagger, openapi

I have 2 application which application A is exposing API for application B to consume.

Application A is generating the swagger.json for application B, and application B is using swagger-codegen to generate the model code.

In my application A which is using Jackson with polymorphic with WRAPPER_OBJECT

```
@JsonTypeInfo (use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = 
JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "doggy"), 
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "kitty")})
@ApiModel(subTypes = {Dog.class, Cat.class}, discriminator = "type")
public abstract class Animal {
}

@ApiModel(value = "kitty", parent = Animal.class)
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public int lives = 9;
}

@ApiModel(value = "doggy", parent = Animal.class)
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public double barkVolume = 100d;
}
```

which expecting the json format to be wrapped.

```
{
    "kitty": {
        "lives": 9
    }
}
```

so when application A is generated the swagger.json using springfox, it generated as below.

```
"Animal": {
    "type": "object",
    "discriminator": "type",
    "title": "Animal"
},
"doggy": {
    "title": "doggy",
    "allOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Animal"
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "barkVolume": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "format": "double"
                }
            },
            "title": "doggy"
        }
    ]
},
"kitty": {
    "title": "kitty",
    "allOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Animal"
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "lives": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                }
            },
            "title": "kitty"
        }
    ]
}
```

But the problem come when the swagger.json is giving to application B to generate the code, the code generated without wrapped.

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2019-08-28T12:54:58.555+08:00")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Kitty.class, name = "kitty"), @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Doggy.class, name = "doggy"),})
public class Animal {
}
```

and when the json is generated as below.

```
{
    "type": "kitty",
    "lives": 9
}
```

i try to check swagger-codegen code, seem that the code alway generated it as JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY.

i just wonder if is that any option in the swagger.json which can define the jackson object can be generated as WARPPER_OBJECT?

Comment: Did you got any solution for this?